# Transform collective to array in Laravel, Laravel 5

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent, laravel-collection

How can I transform this collection to array and eject "whereNotIn" using a Laravel query, like this:

```
->whereNotIn('id', ['collection'])->get();'


Collection {#259 ▼
#items: array:3 [▼
0 => {#257 ▼
  +"id": 2
}
1 => {#256 ▼
  +"id": 3
}
2 => {#237 ▼
  +"id": 6
}
]}
```

Comment: Whats your question exactly? If you want to convert to array, just use the toArray method

Comment: i want to use the method 'whereNotIn' and i dont knwo how to pass the laravel coletion to array
->whereNotIn('id', [array])->get();'

Comment: `->get()->toArray()` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In fact, to get an array, you should use `pluck` together with the `all()` method, so in this case you should use:

```
->whereNotIn('id', $collection->pluck('id')->all())->get();
```

Answer (score 2):

Use [`pluck(attribute)`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/collections#method-pluck):

```
->whereNotIn('id', $collection->pluck('id'))->get();
```